# regular expressions wrapped inside {}

Tags: c#, regex

Am little stuck and wondering if anyone can help, am trying to use regular expressions to find value & check Funtion2 is between the {} in the following string see below:

```
AA \\*Funtion1 {5 + \\*Funtion2 {3} {4} + 6 } BB 

CC \\*Funtion2 {3} {\\*Funtion2 {3} {4} + 4} DD \\*Funtion2 {3} {4} EE

AA \\*Funtion1 { \\*Funtion2 {3} {4} + \\*Funtion2 {3} {4} + 6 } BB
```

Should return 2 matchs but keep getting 3.

Comment: Can you provide the Regex you are currently using so we can see what you are doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it's 'Funtion' and not 'Function'?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a lookbehind.

```
(?<=\{[^}]*)Funtion2
```

This will find 'Funtion2' that is preceded by '{' but does not have a '}' between the opening brace and the text.

Note, however, that this does not balance opening and closing braces. From your example text, I don't see this being a problem.

This will fail to find all matches if the following scenario occurred:

```
AA \\*Funtion1 { \\*Funtion2 {3} {4} + \\*Funtion2 {3} {4} + 6 } BB
```

The second 'Funtion2' would be skipped because there's a '}' between it and the opening '{'.

You could use a balanced regex, but honestly this looks like parsing to me. Perhaps you should consider writing a parser and not relying so heavily on regexes.

Comment: Hi Cyborgx, thanks for your reply. I've taken look at balanced regex and could do with some advice. Got the following am I the right lines? (?<=\{[^}]*)Funtion2\{(?:(.*?)|(?<open> \{)|(?<-open> \}))+\}

Comment: @Chris, you should add that information to the question.  You'll get more eyes on the problem that way, and it's practically unreadable where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Will there ever be braces within braces, as in `{3 + { whatever } }`?  Will there ever be backslashes that are not part of a function name (e.g. `\\*Funtion2`)?  If the answer to both questions is no, you should be able to manage this without resorting to balanced groups.  For example:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\{[^{}\\]*\\\\\*Funtion2(?:[^{}\\]+\{[^{}\\]+\})*[^{}\\]*\}");
foreach (Match m in r.Matches(source)
{
  Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

result:

```
{5 + \\*Funtion2 {3} {4} + 6 }
{\\*Funtion2 {3} {4} + 4}
```

Breaking the regex down, we have:

```
\{              # the opening brace
[^{}\\]*        # optional stuff preceding the function name
\\\\            # the two backslashes
\*              # the asterisk
Funtion2        # and the name
(?:             # in a loop...
  [^{}\\]+        # stuff preceding the next opening brace
  \{[^{}\\]+\}    # a balanced pair of braces with non-braces in between
)*              # loop zero or more times
[^{}\\]*        # optional stuff preceding the closing brace
\}              # the closing brace
```